# How to Simplify $ \frac{\sin(3x)+\sin^3(x)}{\cos(3x)-\cos^3(x)} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Simplify $$ \frac{\sin(3x)+\sin^3(x)}{\cos(3x)-\cos^3(x)}.$$
>   The solution is : $-\cot(x)$

I tried to: $$\frac{\sin(2x)\cos(x)+\cos(2x)\sin(x)+\sin^3(x)}{\cos(2x)\cos(x)+\sin(2x)\sin(x)-\cos^3(x)}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one step further you have
$$\sin(3x)   =  - 4 \sin^3 x  +  3 \sin x~~~and~~~\cos 3x  = -3\cos x+4\cos^3x$$that is

$$\sin(3x)   +\sin^3 x =  3\sin x( 1-\sin^2 x  ) = 3\sin x\cos^2x ~~~$$and$$~~~\cos 3x-\cos^3x = -3\cos x( 1-\cos^2x)= -3\cos x\sin^2x$$

Then $$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin^3(x)}{\cos(3x)-\cos^3(x)} =\frac{3\sin x\cos^2x}{-3\cos x\sin^2x} =-\cot x.$$ 
See here: 
http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/geometrytrigequivcos3xetc.aspx

Comment: Nice, thanks for solution and the link.

Comment: @BiliDebili you are welcome all easy details have been added

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\begin{align}\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)&=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^3
\\&=\cos^3(x)+3i\cos^2(x)\sin(x)
-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)-i\sin^3(x).
\end{align}$$
Therefore, after separating real and complex parts, we obtain
$$
\cos(3x)=\cos^3(x)
-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x),\quad
\sin(3x)=3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)
-\sin^3(x).
$$
Finally
$$\frac{\sin(3x)+\sin^3(x)}{\cos(3x)-\cos^3(x)}=\frac{3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)}{-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)}=-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\cot(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know any good learning sites for simplifying expressions like this by going in the complex plane? I think it's way easier than doing addition formulas.

Comment: @BiliDebili Try https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/trig-identities-from-complex/

Comment: Looks like a great site. Thanks!